# probability density function for time bins

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, time-series

My data set includes for each user several times and the number of actions that were done for that user at that time. i.e.

```
user | datetime | number of actions
--------------------------------
AA     10:00      5
AA     12:00      7
```

I'm creating a histogram for the total number of actions of the user (i.e. 1 histogram per user) . My x-axis would be bins of times, i.e. first time slot:0-5 represents hours 0-5, second bin: 6-14, third been: 15-20, forth bin: 21-24. Bins are not of equal sizes. Y-axis the total number of action in that time-period.

I would like to calculate the probability of a user to have an action in a certain time-slot, (bin). Can I use in this case the probability density function of this histogram? i.e. since this is a sort-of-a time series, should I take anything else into consideration?

Comment: Your example and your description contradict each other. You write "My data set includes for each user a time and the number of actions", but in your example you have two times and two numbers of actions for one user.

Comment: Edited, thanks. There could be few lines per user

Comment: Histograms with unequal bin widths can be difficult to make in a consistent way and difficult to interpret. Perhaps you could make a bar chart for each user with the height of each bar representing the number of actions per unit time.